# Securely erase single (Windows) partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am currently dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10.  I know I can "erase" the Windows partition with gparted, but does that really erase the data?

I would like to run something like DBAN on the windows partition before I delete it and expand the Ubuntu one.  This is an older computer (and not my primary) that I have been using to experiment with Ubuntu.   I do not have much data yet, so completely wiping the drive and starting over is a possibility if wiping just the windows partition is not an option.

But, I wanted to ask... Is there any tool that will wipe the windows partition but leave the Ubuntu one intact?

Comment: You could do this, but it seems like extra effort unless you believe that someone is going to take physical posession of your computer, and find something you don't want them to.

Comment: It is my old work computer and has clients' data on it.   I suppose I could wipe individual folders with something like ccleaner or bcwipe.

Comment: You could also look at bleachbit - but - I think that I have read that the normal file wipes are not terribly effective on ext3/ext4 file systems.  I am totally in the dark about NTFS - see `man shred`

Comment: @CharlesGreen actually, I'm a little surprised that any company would release a computer with customer/client data still on the hard drive. I'd think that most companies would physically destroy the hard drive before allowing the computer to leave the premises.

Comment: @heynnema  i am an freelancer so it has always been my computer... it is just old so i was experimenting with Linux for the first time...  now that i want to keep linux on the machine, i was thinking i should wipe the old data on the windows partition before i delete it to expand the linux partition to the full disk

Comment: @Driver8 I understand. Keeping a working copy of Windows doesn't hurt, as you may need it for things like BIOS updates, or device firmware updates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

One method I could device to do this, would be to first use `dd` to overwrite your windows partition, and then use `gparted` to create a new format for use in linux, or remove the old partition and incorporate the space into your existing Linux disk.

Assuming your disk is `/dev/sda` and the Windows partition is `/dev/sda9`, you might try a command like

```
sudo dd --progress ifile=/dev/zero ofile=/dev/sda9 bs=4g
```

This will fill the partition with zero's, and continue until the partition is full and the command returns with an error.  You *could* do the math, and figure a blocksize (bs=) and count (count=) to fill the partition exactly.  Additionally, you could use `/dev/urandom` to fill the partition with random data.
But be very, very careful with dd.

Following this, you could then use gparted to format it as a file system that you would like to use for your Linux system.

Finally, be very careful with `dd`.  It is not a forgiving program.

Comment: Why ext2 partition?

Comment: @heynnema Reduce overhead?  No journal?  Maybe one of the other fs would be faster.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Overhead is minimal, but chance of data loss is non-trivial. Do *not* use ext2 if you plan to be writing to that system a lot. It is useful still for things like `/boot` or similar, but definitely not for anything that user will be writing to a lot. This is a horrible case of micro-optimisation.

Comment: @v010dya  Data loss is exactly what the OP is asking for...

Comment: @CharlesGreen Apologies, i have misunderstood the step where you have used ext2 at. In that case your initial creation of the new partition is useless. Just overwrite the NTFS partition as a block device. `dd` will not care what file system is there, it is writing directly to the drive itself.

Comment: @v010dya You are correct - the whole "make a partition, format..." is useless in this case - I will revise my answer to point to that.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but I hosed the upgrade to 19.04 (wouldn't leave the login screen even after entering pw many times) so i just used the opportunity to wipe the entire hard drive and install 19.04 clean.   As I said, I am just learning so nothing was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Erasing data from the disk in the manner that is definitive is non-trivial. You could attempt to follow [Charles Green's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134792/216568), but there are caveats:

1. Overwriting data once may still leave it recoverable by specialist tools. So you may need to use something stronger than `dd`, for example this command will do this: `sudo wipe -k /dev/sda9` (make sure to put in the correct partition), you do not need to delete the partition and then recreate it, simply do that with the current NTFS partition, it will be wiped.
2. Even if you use `wipe` sometimes harddrives cache the data and only write it when they think it is necessary. So it is possible that your drive will do that, and not actually physically remove the data by overwriting it. `wipe` is better than `dd`, because at least it will do multiple passes lessening the chance of that happening.
3. While these command will overwrite blocks deemed bad by Windows operating system (because you are writing to a block device rather than to a file system), it will be unable to access those sectors that harddrive's firmware has marked as damaged. Contemporary drives silently redirect addresses from the damaged sectors to writable ones, and the data there cannot be overwritten.
4. Since you are concerned about data leak, you may prepare for future issues and encrypt the new drive. You can look at [`dm-crypt`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt), but it is non-trivial. The beauty of this setup is that the data appears to be random if the attacker does not have a password or a keyfile.

Comment: Actually, I'm a little surprised that any company would release a computer with customer/client data still on the hard drive. I'd think that most companies would physically destroy the hard drive before allowing the computer to leave the premises.

Comment: You'll be surprised. Some companies have even been "hacked" by somebody simply looking through their trash and finding paper with passwords written on it.